# Crystal Select expert issue

Tags: crystal-reports, formula, crystal-reports-2008

I am having trouble setting this scenario in Select Expert - Report:

Pull all records from the tables if

There is no ID associated with this form number

OR

There is a ID associated with this form number but the ID_STATUS is not one of 1,2,3

OR

There is a ID associated with this form number but the ID_STATUS is null

My Tryout:

```
( isnull ({EMPLOYEE.ID}) or  
  ( Not isnull ({EMPLOYEE.ID}) and  
    ( not ({EMPLOYEE.ID_STATUS} in [3.00, 2.00, 1.00]) or  
      isnull ( ({EMPLOYEE.ID_STATUS}) )  
    )  
  )
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 2):

There are a few small problems with your code, but what's preventing it from working (probably) is that you're not treating not() as a function on the fifth line. Try this.

```
isnull({EMPLOYEE.ID})
or isnull({EMPLOYEE.ID_STATUS})
or not({EMPLOYEE.ID_STATUS} in [1,2,3])
```

There's no need to check if `not(isnull({EMPLOYEE.ID}))` since there are only two possibilities: either the ID status is null or it isn't.

Comment: I got busy with other reports. I tried but no luck. Actually there are 3 possibilities where I want the employees to show on the report if
 1. ID is null no record for the form number
2. There is a ID record for the form number but the ID_Status is null 
And at the same time the employee could have one more row where 
3. If ID_status is null then ID_Status should not be one of 1,2,3

Comment: @star86 Fixed a typo in the last part of my answer - maybe it's clearer now. The code is still good and should do what you're asking. What is the remaining issue?

Comment: Still does not work... how do I tell crystal to go back and check the employee table again. Maybe I am not explaining it correctly. Here is an e.g.: Employee tbl has form # 5544 has ID 122 , ID_STATUS NULL there is another row for form # 5544 has ID 123 , ID_STATUS 3. In that case I don't want form # 5544 to show on the report.

Comment: @star86 You need to revise your question to include more info on the schema in question and give an example of what you're looking for. It is not clear from your wording that your selection depends on a third column, the form number. It's also not clear how you're trying to display this data on the report.